# MPU6050 how zeromotion works

Tags: c++

Good evening to all. I am currently working on a project with smart windows in which I will measure temperature, humidity acceleration and I will have a gyroscope for the window degrees. I have decided which sensors I will continue with and one of them is the MPU6050. The question I want to ask is how can I use the sensor so that I can take measurements at the end of the acceleration and not at the beginning? The esp32 I have will be asleep all the time and will wake up every 15 minutes to send data out and if it receives an interrupt it will then wake up to send data. I have tried all the cases with motion but I have not succeeded
this is my code for zeromotion

```
#include "Wire.h"
#include "SPI.h"

// I2Cdev and MPU6050 must be installed as libraries, or else the .cpp/.h files
// for both classes must be in the include path of your project
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"

// class default I2C address is 0x68
// specific I2C addresses may be passed as a parameter here
// AD0 low = 0x68 (default for InvenSense evaluation board)
// AD0 high = 0x69
MPU6050 accelgyro;

int16_t ax, ay, az;
int16_t gx, gy, gz;
int8_t threshold, count;
float temp;
bool zero_detect;
bool TurnOnZI = false;

bool XnegMD, XposMD, YnegMD, YposMD, ZnegMD, ZposMD;
int minVal=265; int maxVal=402;
double x; double y; double z;

#define LED_PIN 13
#define BUTTON_PIN_BITMASK 0x200000000 // 2^33 in hex
RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootCount = 0;


bool blinkState = false;
void print_wakeup_reason() {
  esp_sleep_wakeup_cause_t wakeup_reason;

  wakeup_reason = esp_sleep_get_wakeup_cause();

  switch (wakeup_reason)
  {
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT0 : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by external signal using RTC_IO"); break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT1 : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by external signal using RTC_CNTL"); break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TIMER : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by timer"); break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TOUCHPAD : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by touchpad"); break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_ULP : Serial.println("Wakeup caused by ULP program"); break;
    default : Serial.printf("Wakeup was not caused by deep sleep: %d\n", wakeup_reason); break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  // join I2C bus (I2Cdev library doesn't do this automatically)
  Wire.begin();

  // initialize serial communication
  // (38400 chosen because it works as well at 8MHz as it does at 16MHz, but
  // it's really up to you depending on your project)
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //Increment boot number and print it every reboot
  ++bootCount;
  Serial.println("Boot number: " + String(bootCount));

  //Print the wakeup reason for ESP32
  print_wakeup_reason();
  // initialize device
  Serial.println("Initializing I2C devices...");
  accelgyro.initialize();

  // verify connection
  Serial.println("Testing device connections...");
  Serial.println(accelgyro.testConnection() ? "MPU6050 connection successful" : "MPU6050 connection failed");
  esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(GPIO_NUM_15, 1); //1 = High, 0 = Low

  //accelgyro.setTempSensorEnabled(false);
  
  //Set up zero motion

  /** Get accelerometer power-on delay.
    The accelerometer data path provides samples to the sensor registers, Motion
    detection, Zero Motion detection, and Free Fall detection modules. The
    signal path contains filters which must be flushed on wake-up with new
    samples before the detection modules begin operations. The default wake-up
    delay, of 4ms can be lengthened by up to 3ms. This additional delay is
    specified in ACCEL_ON_DELAY in units of 1 LSB = 1 ms. The user may select
    any value above zero unless instructed otherwise by InvenSense. Please refer
    to Section 8 of the MPU-6000/MPU-6050 Product Specification document for
    further information regarding the detection modules.
    @return Current accelerometer power-on delay
    @see MPU60X0_RA_MOT_DETECT_CTRL
    @see MPU60X0_DETECT_ACCEL_ON_DELAY_BIT
  */
  accelgyro.setAccelerometerPowerOnDelay(3);


  /** Get Zero Motion Detection interrupt enabled status.
    Will be set 0 for disabled, 1 for enabled.
    @return Current interrupt enabled status
    @see MPU60X0_RA_INT_ENABLE
    @see MPU60X0_INTERRUPT_ZMOT_BIT
  **/
  accelgyro.setIntZeroMotionEnabled(true);

  //accelgyro.setIntMotionEnabled(true);


  /** Get the high-pass filter configuration.
    The DHPF is a filter module in the path leading to motion detectors (Free
    Fall, Motion threshold, and Zero Motion). The high pass filter output is not
    available to the data registers (see Figure in Section 8 of the MPU-6000/
    MPU-6050 Product Specification document).

    The high pass filter has three modes:
       Reset: The filter output settles to zero within one sample. This
              effectively disables the high pass filter. This mode may be toggled
              to quickly settle the filter.

       On:    The high pass filter will pass signals above the cut off frequency.

       Hold:  When triggered, the filter holds the present sample. The filter
              output will be the difference between the input sample and the held
              sample.

    ACCEL_HPF | Filter Mode | Cut-off Frequency
    ----------+-------------+------------------
    0         | Reset       | None
    1         | On          | 5Hz
    2         | On          | 2.5Hz
    3         | On          | 1.25Hz
    4         | On          | 0.63Hz
    7         | Hold        | None
    </pre>

    @return Current high-pass filter configuration
    @see MPU60X0_DHPF_RESET
    @see MPU60X0_RA_ACCEL_CONFIG
  */
  //DEBUG_PRINTLN("Setting DHPF bandwidth to 5Hz...");
  accelgyro.setDHPFMode(1);


  /** Get motion detection event acceleration threshold.
    This register configures the detection threshold for Motion interrupt
    generation. The unit of MOT_THR is 1LSB = 2mg. Motion is detected when the
    absolute value of any of the accelerometer measurements exceeds this Motion
    detection threshold. This condition increments the Motion detection duration
    counter (Register 32). The Motion detection interrupt is triggered when the
    Motion Detection counter reaches the time count specified in MOT_DUR
    (Register 32).

    The Motion interrupt will indicate the axis and polarity of detected motion
    in MOT_DETECT_STATUS (Register 97).

    For more details on the Motion detection interrupt, see Section 8.3 of the
    MPU-6000/MPU-6050 Product Specification document as well as Registers 56 and
    58 of this document.

    @return Current motion detection acceleration threshold value (LSB = 2mg)
    @see MPU60X0_RA_MOT_THR
  */
  //Serial.println("Setting motion detection threshold to 16...");
  //accelgyro.setMotionDetectionThreshold(16);


  /** Get zero motion detection event acceleration threshold.
    This register configures the detection threshold for Zero Motion interrupt
    generation. The unit of ZRMOT_THR is 1LSB = 2mg. Zero Motion is detected when
    the absolute value of the accelerometer measurements for the 3 axes are each
    less than the detection threshold. This condition increments the Zero Motion
    duration counter (Register 34). The Zero Motion interrupt is triggered when
    the Zero Motion duration counter reaches the time count specified in
    ZRMOT_DUR (Register 34).

    Unlike Free Fall or Motion detection, Zero Motion detection triggers an
    interrupt both when Zero Motion is first detected and when Zero Motion is no
    longer detected.

    When a zero motion event is detected, a Zero Motion Status will be indicated
    in the MOT_DETECT_STATUS register (Register 97). When a motion-to-zero-motion
    condition is detected, the status bit is set to 1. When a zero-motion-to-
    motion condition is detected, the status bit is set to 0.

    For more details on the Zero Motion detection interrupt, see Section 8.4 of
    the MPU-6000/MPU-6050 Product Specification document as well as Registers 56
    and 58 of this document.

    @return Current zero motion detection acceleration threshold value (LSB = 2mg)
    @see MPU60X0_RA_ZRMOT_THR
  */
  Serial.println("Setting zero-motion detection threshold to 156...");
  accelgyro.setZeroMotionDetectionThreshold(64);


  /** Get motion detection event duration threshold.
    This register configures the duration counter threshold for Motion interrupt
    generation. The duration counter ticks at 1 kHz, therefore MOT_DUR has a unit
    of 1LSB = 1ms. The Motion detection duration counter increments when the
    absolute value of any of the accelerometer measurements exceeds the Motion
    detection threshold (Register 31). The Motion detection interrupt is
    triggered when the Motion detection counter reaches the time count specified
    in this register.

    For more details on the Motion detection interrupt, see Section 8.3 of the
    MPU-6000/MPU-6050 Product Specification document.

    @return Current motion detection duration threshold value (LSB = 1ms)
    @see MPU60X0_RA_MOT_DUR
  */
  Serial.println("Setting motion detection duration to 40...");
  //accelgyro.setMotionDetectionDuration(2);


  /** Get zero motion detection event duration threshold.
    This register configures the duration counter threshold for Zero Motion
    interrupt generation. The duration counter ticks at 16 Hz, therefore
    ZRMOT_DUR has a unit of 1 LSB = 64 ms. The Zero Motion duration counter
    increments while the absolute value of the accelerometer measurements are
    each less than the detection threshold (Register 33). The Zero Motion
    interrupt is triggered when the Zero Motion duration counter reaches the time
    count specified in this register.

    For more details on the Zero Motion detection interrupt, see Section 8.4 of
    the MPU-6000/MPU-6050 Product Specification document, as well as Registers 56
    and 58 of this document.

    @return Current zero motion detection duration threshold value (LSB = 64ms)
    @see MPU60X0_RA_ZRMOT_DUR
  */
  //Serial.println("Setting zero-motion detection duration to 0...");
  accelgyro.setZeroMotionDetectionDuration(64);
  
  //for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    // read raw accel/gyro measurements from device
    Serial.println("Getting raw accwl/gyro measurements");
    //accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);

    Serial.println("Getting Motion indicators, count and threshold");

    XnegMD = accelgyro.getXNegMotionDetected();
    XposMD = accelgyro.getXPosMotionDetected();
    YnegMD = accelgyro.getYNegMotionDetected();
    YposMD = accelgyro.getYPosMotionDetected();
    ZnegMD = accelgyro.getZNegMotionDetected();
    ZposMD = accelgyro.getZPosMotionDetected();

    zero_detect = accelgyro.getIntMotionStatus();
    threshold = accelgyro.getZeroMotionDetectionThreshold();

    //Serial.println("Got to count");
    //count = accelgyro.getMotionDetectionCounterDecrement();

    /** Get current internal temperature.
      @return Temperature reading in 16-bit 2's complement format
      @see MPU60X0_RA_TEMP_OUT_H
    */
    Serial.println("Getting Die Temperature");
    temp = (accelgyro.getTemperature() / 340.) + 36.53;


    /*  The accelerometer and gyroscope measurements are explained in the MPU-6050
      datasheet in the GYRO_CONFIG and ACCEL_CONFIG register descriptions (sections 4.4
      and 4.5 on pages 14 and 15). The scale of each depends on the sensitivity settings
      chosen, which can be one of +/- 2, 4, 8, or 16g for the accelerometer and one of
      +/- 250, 500, 1000, or 2000 deg/sec for the gyroscope. The accelerometer produces data
      in units of acceleration (distance over time2), and the gyroscope produces data in units
      of rotational velocity (rotation distance over time).

      The output scale for any setting is [-32768, +32767] for each of the six axes. The default
      setting in the I2Cdevlib class is +/- 2g for the accel and +/- 250 deg/sec for the gyro. If
      the device is perfectly level and not moving, then:
          X/Y accel axes should read 0
          Z accel axis should read 1g, which is +16384 at a sensitivity of 2g
          X/Y/Z gyro axes should read 0

      In reality, the accel axes won't read exactly 0 since it is difficult to be perfectly level
      and there is some noise/error, and the gyros will also not read exactly 0 for the same reason
      (noise/error).
    */

    // these methods (and a few others) are also available
    accelgyro.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);
    accelgyro.getRotation(&gx, &gy, &gz);

//    Serial.print(temp); Serial.print(",");
//    Serial.print(ax / 16384.); Serial.print(",");
//    Serial.print(ay / 16384.); Serial.print(",");
//    Serial.print(az / 16384.); Serial.print(",");
//    Serial.print(gx / 131.072); Serial.print(",");
//    Serial.print(gy / 131.072); Serial.print(",");
//    Serial.print(gz / 131.072); Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(zero_detect); Serial.print(",");
    //Serial.print(XnegMD); Serial.print(",");
    //Serial.println(XposMD);

  int xAng = map(ax,minVal,maxVal,-90,90); 
    int yAng = map(ay,minVal,maxVal,-90,90); 
    int zAng = map(az,minVal,maxVal,-90,90);

x= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -zAng)+PI); 
y= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-xAng, -zAng)+PI); 
z= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -xAng)+PI);

Serial.print("AngleX= "); Serial.println(x);

Serial.print("AngleY= "); Serial.println(y);

Serial.print("AngleZ= "); Serial.println(z);
    
    // display tab-separated accel/gyro x/y/z values
    /*
      Serial.print("a/g:\t");
      Serial.print(ax/16384.); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(ay/16384.); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(az/16384.); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(gx/131.072); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(gy/131.072); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.println(gz/131.072);

      Serial.print("DieTemp:\t");Serial.println(temp);

      Serial.print("ZeroMotion(97):\t");
      Serial.print(zero_detect); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("Count: \t");Serial.print(count); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(XnegMD); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(XposMD); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(YnegMD); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(YposMD); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(ZnegMD); Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.println(ZposMD);
    */


   // delay(1000);

    // blink LED to indicate activity
    //    blinkState = !blinkState;
    //    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, blinkState);
  //}


  // configure Arduino LED for
  //pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Going to sleep now");
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
  Serial.println("This will never be printed");

}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about these devices or sensors, I just looked at your code.  There's a large block of comments above the `setZeroMotionDetectionThreshold` call which states that you get an interrupt when acceleration begins, and another interrupt when it's no longer detected.  It goes on to explain how to determine what type of motion state transition is occurring.  So I'm not really sure what you're asking.  You just need to read this carefully and handle the interrupt in the way it's designed.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply @paddy.
my goal is to make sure the sensor does not wake up the first time it receives an interrupt but as soon as the acceleration is over. for example when I want to open the window the sensor does not send data but when I stop the movement from the window.

Comment: What I am saying, is that according to this documentation, you get an interrupt in both cases and so you can examine the state and choose whether it's an event where you want to send data.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your general concept. Opening a window can happen in "portions". So you can expect to get several motion-start and motion-stop interrupts. What you should do is: At first interrupt leave the device awake for - say - 3 seconds. If further interrupts come in, then restart your timer  (called "retriggering" in HW timers). When the 3 seconds are gone, read the sensor to get the new window angle, send this info out, and then go to deep sleep again.